# Microsoft Edge does not recognize content-type html

Tags: html, content-type, microsoft-edge

The following html is not recognised by MS Edge(Windows 10) and it downloads html as a file instead of rendering. It renders as html in Chrome and FireFox without any issues. The error is repeatable on other machines and IE 10

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the file content, but with HTTP headers. You have to make sure that server sends proper Content-Type header, for example:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Aaargh, I found the problem: The html that was downloading came from a .php file which included a PHP directive:

```
header('Content-Type: charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

This was overriding the content-type setting in default header html which was then downloaded as text as displayed in my original question above. This then made me think it was a MS Edge issue  when in reality FireFox and Chrome must assume HTML as default content-type but Edge clearly does not. Anyhow, this change in php directive fixed the issue:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```